# Error when uploading large file in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I upload file file which size grate than 100mb then server error -
" The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. "

How can i fix it, I host my laravel project on cpanel.

I want to upload large files on server like file size below 1 gb.